# Usando OpenCV para monitorear habitación

Tags: python, opencv

Soy nuevo usando opencv y en python, mi proyecto es para una casa inteligente.

Logre instalar opencv en una raspberrypi y usando una webcam.

Mi programa va trabajar en los siguientes tres escenarios.

1. Una persona entra en el cuarto, detecta la cara y la persona, envía mensaje "Papá esta en cuarto 1".
2. Una persona entra en el cuarto, detecta la cara pero no a la persona, envía mensaje "Persona desconocida esta en cuarto 1"
3. Nadie esta en el cuarto, envíar mensaje "Nadie esta en el cuarto 1"

Los escenarios 1 y 2 tengo idea de como resolverlos, pero donde estoy atorado es en el esceanrio 3. He tratado de guardar el nombre de la persona detectada en una variable, si esta es vacia debe mandar el mensaje, pero no me ha funcionado.

El código que estoy usando es el siguiente, el problema que tengo se encuentra al final del código:

```
import cv2, sys, numpy, os
size = 1
fn_haar = 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
fn_dir = 'att_faces'

# Parte 1: Crea fisherRecognizer
print('Training...')

# Crea lista de imagenes y una lista correspondiente a los nombres
(images, lables, names, id) = ([], [], {}, 0)

# Obtiene los directorios de donde esta la informacion de training
for (subdirs, dirs, files) in os.walk(fn_dir):

    # Itera cada directorio para obtener las fotos
    for subdir in dirs:
        names[id] = subdir
        subjectpath = os.path.join(fn_dir, subdir)

        # Itera cada foto en el directorio
        for filename in os.listdir(subjectpath):

            # Descarta imagenes que no esten el formato correcto
            f_name, f_extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
            if(f_extension.lower() not in
                    ['.png','.jpg','.jpeg','.gif','.pgm']):
                print("Skipping "+filename+", wrong file type")
                continue
            path = subjectpath + '/' + filename
            lable = id

            # Se añaden a la información de Training
            images.append(cv2.imread(path, 0))
            lables.append(int(lable))
        id += 1
(im_width, im_height) = (112, 92)

# Crea una matriz Numpy de los datos anteriores
(images, lables) = [numpy.array(lis) for lis in [images, lables]]

# OpenCV entrea el modelo con las fotos
model = cv2.face.createFisherFaceRecognizer()
model.train(images, lables)




# Parte 2: Usar fisherRecognizer en camara web
haar_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(fn_haar)
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:

    # Itera hasta que la webcam se encienda
    rval = False
    while(not rval):
        # coloca la imagen de la webcam en un 'frame'
        (rval, frame) = webcam.read()
        if(not rval):
            print("Failed to open webcam. Trying again...")

    # Gira la imagen (opcional)
    frame=cv2.flip(frame,1,0)

    # Convierte a escalas grises
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Escala la imagen para agilizar (opcional, cambiar tamaño)
    mini = cv2.resize(gray, (int(gray.shape[1] / size), int(gray.shape[0] / size)))

    # Detecta cara e itera en las imagenes
    faces = haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(mini)
    for i in range(len(faces)):
        face_i = faces[i]

        # Coordina un recuadro en la cara
        (x, y, w, h) = [v * size for v in face_i]
        face = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        face_resize = cv2.resize(face, (im_width, im_height))

        # Trata de reconocer la cara
        prediction = model.predict(face_resize)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)

        # [1]
        # Escribe el nombre reconocido en el cuadro pintado
        cv2.putText(frame,
           '%s - %.0f' % (names[prediction[0]],prediction[1]),
           (x-10, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,1,(0, 255, 0))
           face = '%S' % (names[prediction[0]]) #Guardar nombre en variable
           #Se inicia validación de texto
           if face != "" : #Si se obtiene un nombre
               print(face + "Esta En El Cuarto..") #Pintar el nombre en la terminal
           elif face == "" : #Si no se obtiene un nombre
               print("No hay nadie en el cuarto...") #Pintar texto
               #Esta ultima parte es donde tengo problemas, cuando no detecta una cara, no me pinta nada en la terminal
    # Muestra la imagen en pantalla y espera por la tecal ESC para finalizar
    cv2.imshow('OpenCV', frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if key == 27:
        break
```

El código que estoy usando esta basado en el siguiente tutorial:
[Reconocimiento Facial (En ingles)](https://noahingham.com/blog/facerec-python.html)

Cualquier ayuda es apreciada, gracias. Saludos.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Si no sabes cómo hacer lo que describes en tu pregunta, investiga primero y actualiza tu pregunta con los enlaces de la investigación que hayas hecho. Hasta que no añadas mas información, me temo que tu pregunta quedará [en espera-¿Qué significa si una pregunta está "cerrada" o "en espera"?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: ¿Por qué no activas el script sólo cuando detecte movimiento? Normalmente, las aplicaciones comerciales que hacen esta misma funcionalidad tienen la siguiente lógica. ¿movimiento?->¿cara?->Reconocida o no. Si no la reconoce te las muestra más tarde y tú tienes que decirle quién era.

Answer (score 0):

Está claro que nunca se va a dar el caso que tú propones `face== ""` puesto que `face` siempre es asignada.

Tal y como lo has desarrollado, creo que la mejor opción es establecer un factor de confianza, por ejemplo 0.5.

Si no me equivoco, en `prediction[1]` almacenas la confianza de predicción. Si dicho valor es >0.5, digamos que tienes la certeza de identificar a la persona, así que muestras el mensaje con su nombre. En caso contrario, muestras el mensaje de que no se conoce a la persona.

```
# Trata de reconocer la cara
    prediction = model.predict(face_resize)
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)

    msg = ""
    if prediction[1]>0.5:
        msg = prediction[0]+" esta en el cuarto."
    else:
        msg = "No hay nadie en el cuarto..."

    print(msg)

    # [1]
    # Escribe el nombre reconocido en el cuadro pintado
    cv2.putText(frame,
       '%s - %.0f' % (names[prediction[0]],prediction[1]),
       (x-10, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,1,(0, 255, 0))
       face = '%S' % (names[prediction[0]]) #Guardar nombre en variable

# Muestra la imagen en pantalla y espera por la tecal ESC para finalizar
cv2.imshow('OpenCV', frame)
key = cv2.waitKey(10)
if key == 27:
    break
```